# Help to understand this proof in this number theory book

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading [Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery's an Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://www.fuchs-braun.com/media/532896481f9c1c47ffff8077fffffff0.pdf) and I didn't understand the following theorem on page 132:

[image]
[image]
[image]

***My doubts:***

1. Why is there such $j'$ such that $jj'\equiv a \pmod p$?
2. Why are there $(p-1)/2$ pairs?
3. Why does it follow $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv (p-1)!\pmod p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) For $0\neq j<p$ we have $\gcd(j,p)=1$. This means there are integers $s,t$ such that $sj+tp=1$. (Bezout). And so $sj\equiv1\pmod p$ . Now multiply this final congruence equation by $a$  and define  $j'=as$, we get  $jj'\equiv a\pmod p$.

(2) $x^2=a\pmod p$ has no solution means, to get the product  value as $a$ one has to multiply *two distinct* numbers. So in $jj'\equiv a\pmod p$ $j\neq j'$.

(3) the numbers 1 to $p-1$ are multiplied to get $(p-1)!$, Now rearange this multiplication with $j'$ following $j$. So $(p-1)/2$ pairs in this rearranged product each pair multiplying to $a$, yielding $a^{p-1/2}$

Comment: Why $j'=as<p$? thank you!

Comment: Ok. All numbers are to be reduced to their residues mod p.

Comment: How can I prove this formally? We know that $sa\equiv t\pmod p$ for $1<t<p$, so what?

Comment: Originally we had $asj\equiv a\pmod p$. Yes $as$ could be bigger than $p$. So divide it by $p$  with remainder getting $as= qp+j'$ with $j'<p$ as remainder. Substituting we get $(qp+j')j=a\pmod p $. The term $qpj$ can be omitted as it is a multiple of $p$. So we get $j'j\equiv a\pmod p$.